# Avoid PHP engine crashes with ZVAL_STRING

Tags: php, c, windows, linux

In an extension, what can I do to avoid the crash of the php engine when zval string is allocated by myself ?

```
..
// will do implicitly ZVAL_STRING("tmp", "/tmp", 0); 
// 
SET_VAR_STRING("tmp", "/tmp");
..

php_embed_shutdown(TSRMLS_C);   // GPF !!
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
SET_VAR_STRING("tmp", estrdup("/tmp"));
```